# Custom Javascript Won't Run in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla, conflict

I am using `Joomla-3` for my websites and I have created a simple small `JavaScript(ajax)` file which I attached through the template config file(as seen on the template's documentation).

I also added my `html` in an article(without `TinyMCE` etc so I know it accepts my code). The script works fine in a simple `.html` or `.php` file but it doesn't work along with `Joomla`.

My script has 2 dependent `ajax` dropdown menus(static content). Do you have any ideas on what could go wrong?

Thank you in advance!

PS. You can find the code of my JavaScript [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fHah6/).

Here's the code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  var services = [];

  services['service1'] = [{
      "name": "Giannis",
      "url": "giannis"
    }, {
      "name": "Kostas",
      "url": "kostas"
    }, {
      "name": "Fillipos",
      "url": "fillipos"
    }
  ];
  services['service2'] = [{
      "name": "Maria",
      "url": "maria"
    }, {
      "name": "Peter",
      "url": "peter"
    }, {
      "name": "Jack",
      "url": "jack"
    }
  ];

  services['service3'] = [{
      "name": "Dimitris",
      "url": "dimitris"
    }, {
      "name": "Takis",
      "url": "takis"
    }, {
      "name": "Gianna",
      "url": "gianna"
    }
  ];


  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#services").change(function () {
      var selectedService = $(this).val();
      $('#doctors').children().remove();
      $('#doctors').append('<option value="Null">Click to select a Doctor</option>');
      jQuery.each(services[selectedService], function (ind, val) {
        $('#doctors').append('<option value="' + this.url + '">' + this.name + '</option>');
      })
    });

    jQuery("#doctors").change(function () {
      var redirServ = $('#services option:selected').val();
      var thePersonObject = services[redirServ];
      var goThere = $(this).val();
      var fullurl = 'http://www.website.com/our-services/' + redirServ + '/item/' + goThere;
      alert(fullurl);
      //location.href = 'http://www.website.com/our-services/' + redirServ + '/item/' + goThere; 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: what firebug shows you..?

Comment: how can I check it?
If i type in the console "jQuery("#services").change('service1');", it just returns "[select#services.classselect]"

Comment: I've already opened it but don't know what to look for. Sorry.

Comment: does firebug shows you any error..?

Comment: No. I also tried it in another single file (test.php for example) and it works. The problem is only with joomla.

Comment: make sure you `id's` are all unique in `HTML` page.

Comment: Actually I tried the Chrome console and I see that it returs an error.
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: I Finally figured it out. The issue was that I didn't close the function properly. Thanks for your help with the console!

Comment: welcome bro...+1 for learn using console..

Comment: Thank you very much :) Hope to help people at some point!

Answer (score -1):

Tried this?
$(window).on(‘load’, function(){
// AWESOMENESS
})